# How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on listbox?

Tags: css

as u can see my fiddle outline remove technic for buttons and anchors, doesn't work for 
listboxes :

CSS

```
select::-moz-focus-inner
{
    border: 0;
    outline : 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<select size="4">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
    <option>d</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8jjG/1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove the outline

```
select{
    outline : none;
}
```